# I want a link to the title slug to open from the lightbox

Tags: jquery, css, image, lightbox

The way it sits, the link opens to a photo in lightbox. I added a Title, no problem. I try to add a link from the title and I get nothing. Any help will be great. Just using standard lightbox and css that comes with.

```
<a href="{{ asset('uploads/'.$image->image_name. '.' . $image->type) }}" data-lightbox= "{{ asset('uploads/'.$image->image_name. '.' . $image->type) }}" title="{{{ $image->title }}}">
```

Original code opens to image.php rather than image. I wish to get the image title in lightbox to open to the image.php

```
<a href="{{ url('image/'.$image->id.'/'.$image->slug) }}">
```

Comment: Is the `title` attribute supposed to have triple curly brackets?

Comment: yes that is how the script is written, it shows the title attributed to the image. I wish to link that to the permalink {{ url('image/'.$image->id.'/'.$image->slug) }}

Comment: I did not write the script, it is a customization of a codecanyon project. Did not originally come with lightbox you can see in action at picistry.com